# how to use erlang lists:map function

Tags: erlang

The following is a erlang function. I don't understand how lists:map function is used here.
Could someone please explain?

```
% perform M runs with N calls to F in each run.
% For each of the M runs, determine the average time per call.
% Return, the average and standard deviation of these M results.

time_it(F, N, M) ->
      G = fun() -> F(), ok end,
      NN = lists:seq(1, N),
      MM = lists:seq(1, M),
      T = lists:map(
            fun(_) ->
          T0 = now(),               % start timer
          [ G() || _ <- NN ],           % make N calls to F
          1.0e-6*timer:now_diff(now(), T0)/N    % average time per call
        end,
        MM
          ),
      { avg(T), std(T) }.
```

Thanks.

also, I don't know the proper syntax when using this function. For example, I have a dummy() function take 1 parameter. I get an error while trying to time the dummy function.

```
moduleName:time_it(moduleName:dummy/1, 10, 100).
```

the above would evaluate to illegal expression.

Actually, now with the correct syntax, the function can be invoked correctly with:

```
moduleName:time_it(fun moduleName:dummy/1, 10, 100).
```

However, it will throw a exception saying invoking dummy function without passing any parameter. I think this line is the villain, `[ G() || _ <- NN ],` I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: What's the reason for `G = fun() -> F(), ok end` instead of directly calling `F()` NN times?

Comment: My initial guess was that this was a mistaken optimization to "throw away" the output of F() in case by accumulating it in the list comprehension it slowed things down. So I tried it and it does make a difference! If your F outputs something like a list of 255 integers, then running it enough times is slower inside a list comprehension than calling G(). Perhaps this is due to the overhead of building up the list.
Using lists:foreach is a better solution - this is much faster than the list comprehension, and no need to nest the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`map` is used here to execute the function

```
T0 = now(),                           % start timer
[ G() || _ <- NN ],                   % make N calls to F
1.0e-6*timer:now_diff(now(), T0)/N    % average time per call
```

for each element of `MM`. `map` will return a new list of the same size, where each element of the new list is the result of applying the above function to the corresponding element of `MM`.

You can invoke `time_it` like:

```
moduleName:time_it(fun moduleName:dummy/1, 10, 100).
```

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of `lists:map` in the `time_it` function is just to run the inner function M times. When you see this pattern:

```
L = lists:seq(1,M),
lists:map(fun(_)-> Foo() end, L)
```

It just means call `Foo()` again and again M times, and return the results of each call in a list. It actually makes a list of integers `[1,2,3,...N]` and then calls `Foo()` once for each member of the list.
The author of `time_it` does this same trick again, because `time_it` needs to call the function you give it N*M times. So inside the outer loop that runs M times they use a different technique to run the inner loop N times:

```
L = lists:seq(1,N),
[Foo() || _ <- L]
```

This has exactly the same result as the code above, but this time `Foo` is called N times.

The reason you are having trouble using `time_it` with your dummy function is that `time_it` takes a function with 0 parameters, not 1. So you need to make a dummy function and call it like this:

```
dummy() -> 
    %% do something here you want to measure
    ok.

measure_dummy() ->
    time_it(fun someModule:dummy/0, 10, 100).
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function moduleName:dummy/1 you can do one of the following

1. If you can edit `time_it/3`, then make it call `F(constant_parameter)` instead of `F()`.  I assume this is the case.
2. Otherwise, call `M1:time_it(fun() -> M2:dummy(constant_parameter) end, N, M)`.
   dummy will not be called directly, but only by F inside time_it.

Answer (score 0):

```
results(N, F) when N >= 0 -> results(N, F, []).
results(0, _, Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc);
results(N, F, Acc) -> results(N-1, F, [F() | Acc]).

repeat(0, F) -> ok;
repeat(N, F) when N > 0 ->
    F(),
    repeat(N-1, F).
```

With these:

```
T = results(M, fun () ->
                   T0 = now(),
                   repeat(N, G),
                   1.0e-6 * timer:now_diff(now(), T0)/N
               end)
```

Make sense, now?